# Uploaded home page picture not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm building a WordPress website for my company. I'm using Elementor and Starter templates as my plugins. I've created a one-page website, and almost everything works just fine except for this landing page picture (and the text styling inside that container). In the Elementor editor, everything is working fine and it looks nice, but when I hit publish and then the preview button, this landing page part is not showing the photo I used (there is just nothing, just white), and the text I centered is not aligned correctly.

Everything else seems to work as it should.

I've tried multiple photos (JPEGs), and I've tried building this part from scratch, but nothing seems to work. I also can't really find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing proper in elementor editor and not in the frontend side please try to sync library. I have faced this sync issue several time in past with elementor.

First take back up incase of incident.

How to sync library:
Go to "Elementor" -> "Tools" -> "Sync Library" in the admin panel.

Hope this works :)

If not please share more details like url of the page or something.